# Windows 10 PC does random things: Apps open randomly, Magnifier randomly zooms in to 200, and when I click W, the Pen and Ink thing opens

Tags: windows-10, security, key-binding, application-launch, magnifier

So I had my Windows 10 PC turned on while not doing anything on it other than downloading. Then suddenly these random things started to happen to it one after another:

- **Apps opened randomly**. Also, the Calculator has been opening randomly for the past months/weeks. I think it also opens along with
  other apps for the past weeks/months but I'm not sure because I can't
  remember. I found out that other people were having this same issue as
  well. Their Calculator opens randomly along with other apps.

  Now, my Calculator opened along with other apps and I'm sure of that
  because I remember it. Then after this happened, the issue below followed
  instantly:
- **Magnifier randomly opens and zooms to 200.** I found out that other people were having their Magnifiers randomly opened and zoomed in
  also. But I only found 1 other guy in the internet that said his
  Magnifier  also zoomed specifically to 200 in [this Reddit

  post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/9bh1ex/magnifying_glass_randomly_opened_on_my_pc_am_i/).

  **See what the commenter in his post named vecho05 said:**

  > An old hacking method was to replace the magnifyer with a CMD
  > application or whatever the hacker wants to use. The magnifying glass
  > would be accessable  in the login screen since it is an accessibility
  > application. Since the magnifying app is run as a system app as
  > administrator, it basically gives whatever application that it was
  > replaced by admin privileges. This is enough for me to be concerned
  > about OP's experience.

  **So was a hacker using my Magnifier to hack my PC?**

  **I don't know if any other people got their Magnifier randomly    zoomed in to 200 besides me and and the guy who posted in Reddit.
  Other people who said that their Magnifier randomly zoomed in  might
  have had it zoomed in to 200 as well and just didn't say the specific number. Does me and him having our magnifier zoomed in to  200
  mean that we both had the same PC bug or we both got hacked by the
  same hack that involves zooming the magnifier to 200?**

  Lastly, after this happened, the issue below followed instantly:
- **When I click W, the Pen and Ink/Whiteboard thing opens.** Other people were having this same issue as well.

**All these issues are issues that people have had. But I think that what happened to my PC is different and suspicious because all these issues happened to my PC one after the other. What's also suspicious is all these issues can be related to keyboard issues. Did I get hacked and/or got infected with virus? What do I do to fix all these?**

**I have Avira Antivirus but I don't know if it has scanned my PC after these issues occured. So my PC might have not been scanned for viruses as of now.**

Comment: If you have suspicions don't use it! Format & reinstall.

Comment: There is no real way for anyone here to say, “Aha! That is it!” it could equally be a hardware keyboard malfunction, software keyboard malfunction or *maybe* a hack. The problem with the hacking angle is this: If someone hacked into your PC, would they really make their efforts this obvious? My suggestion is if you have any remote access stuff enabled on the PC, disable it. And if you are worried, just reinstall the OS and see what happens. But remember this: Reinstalling software does not guarantee that the problem will go away if it is a hardware issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Is that the only solution? Can I just download Malwarebytes and scan my PC for malware?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "If someone hacked into your PC, would they really make their efforts this obvious"? I don't think it's obvious because as I said, other people had these a bugs too. People who got this issue might think it's a but it's actually a hack.

Comment: @Diecie If you haven’t downloaded Malwarebytes yet, then this question is really pre-mature. I recommend you download Malwarebytes, have it run and maybe temporarily delete this question until you see what happens. If Malwarebytes doesn’t clear things up, undelete the question and edit it to state you checked with Malwarebytes but still have the issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I didn't download Malwarebytes because my PC might have already been infected with virus and browsers might have virus. Am I right? Can't my browsers have virus which would mean I can't just download Malwarebytes from them?

Comment: The "magnifier hacking" is nonsense. It's only useful if you want to access a computer that you have physical access to, and it breaks the magnifier. Yours works, so that's not it.

Comment: If your computer has a touch screen, it might be malfunctioning and causing virtual clicks.

Comment: @harrymc No, my PC doesn't have a touch screen.

Comment: @gronostaj Are you sure of that? Proof?

Comment: @Diecie The idea behind that trick was that the magnifier on the logon screen is always launched with admin permissions. So if you could replace the magnifier EXE with the cmd EXE, you could start the magnifier on the logon screen and it would actually launch cmd as admin before you're logged in. But that involves replacing the magnifier EXE, which 1) makes it unavailable afterwards and 2) already requires admin permissions or direct access to the drive. If someone would gain admin access remotely they wouldn't have to use this trick in the first place and the magnifier wouldn't work anymore.